# android.intent.action.CALL not opening the default dialer app

Tags: android, android-dialer

I'm running into a problem with building an app. The app has a contact list, when you click a contact the default dialer app should open and place a call to the number associated with the contact. This has been working fine for quite a while but recently we got a question from a user who uses a third-party dialer app, and he would like it to open when clicking a contact from the contact list in our app instead of the stock android dialer.

We installed this third party dialer on a test device and set it was the default dialer app (through apps -> defaults -> default telephony app), however when we click on a contact in our app, the stock (Samsung) dialer still opens, instead of the third party one. We restarted the phone to be sure but this doesn't help either.

When i open the stock contacts app and place a call through there the third party dialer does run correctly and manages the call.

The specific piece of code we use to place the call:

```
Intent intent_call = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL");
intent_call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
startActivity(intent_call);
```

From what I can find in the documentation this should respect the default dialer setting but it seems like it does not. Does anyone have any idea why this could be? I've been searching all over but I can't seem to find any info other than the way we already use through the intent.action.call.